# How to make image link for my website like this https://website.com/image.png in gatsby.config?

Tags: url-routing, gatsby, imageurl, gatsby-image, gatsby-plugin

I want to add image url in meta tag for SEO. But how can I create image link to add in meta tag? I am using gatsby.  I have **src/img/img1.png** image and now I want to create image URLs like this

```
https://website.com/src/img/img1.png
```

How can I do it in gatsby-config.js file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of Gatsby starters comes with a [SEO component](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default/blob/master/src/components/seo.js), that saves you to build one from scratch. Internally, it uses `<Helmet>`, a component that puts everything that is wrapped inside, in the `<header>` tag. So, given:

```
import React from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet"
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"

function SEO({ description, lang, meta, title, image }) {
  const { site } = useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
      query {
        site {
          siteMetadata {
            title
            description
            author
            image
          }
        }
      }
    `
  )

  const metaDescription = description || site.siteMetadata.description
  const defaultTitle = site.siteMetadata?.title

  return (
    <Helmet
      htmlAttributes={{
        lang,
      }}
      title={title}
      titleTemplate={defaultTitle ? `%s | ${defaultTitle}` : null}
      meta={[
        {
          name: `description`,
          content: metaDescription,
        },
        {
          property: `og:title`,
          content: title,
        },
        {
          property: `og:description`,
          content: metaDescription,
        },
        {
          property: `og:type`,
          content: `website`,
        },
        {
          name: `twitter:card`,
          content: `summary`,
        },
        {
          name: `twitter:creator`,
          content: site.siteMetadata?.author || ``,
        },
        {
          name: `twitter:title`,
          content: title,
        },
        {
          name: `twitter:description`,
          content: metaDescription,
        },
      ].concat(meta)}
    />
  )
}

SEO.defaultProps = {
  lang: `en`,
  meta: [],
  description: ``,
}

SEO.propTypes = {
  description: PropTypes.string,
  lang: PropTypes.string,
  meta: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object),
  title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
}

export default SEO
```

You can add og:image property like:

```
{
  name: `og:image`,
  content: site.siteMetadata?.image || image,
},
```

At this point, you can use your image at the `siteMetadata` (set in your `gatsby-config.js`) or pass an image prop to your `SEO` component:

```
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `Gatsby Default Starter`,
    description: `Kick off your next, great Gatsby project with this default starter. This barebones starter ships with the main Gatsby configuration files you might need.`,
    author: `@gatsbyjs`,
    image: `https://website.com/src/img/img1.png`
  },
```

Or:

```
<SEO image="https://website.com/src/img/img1.png" />
```

---

Having your image at `src/img/img1.png`, your have two different workarounds to point to that image.

```
siteMetadata: {
    title: `Gatsby Default Starter`,
    description: `Kick off your next, great Gatsby project with this default starter. This barebones starter ships with the main Gatsby configuration files you might need.`,
    author: `@gatsbyjs`,
    image: `${__dirname}/src/img/img1.png`
  },
```

Then using the previous mentioned methods to get your image using `useStaticQuery` hook.

Moving your image to [`/static` folder](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/images-and-media/static-folder/): everything that is inside the static folder will be cloned to `/public` folder with the same internal structure. So, you can refer to that image directly using:

```
    image: `/img/img1.png`
```

Assuming that your static folder structure is `/static/img/img1.png`

Comment: Actually I have done that but when I hit this url https://website.com/src/img/img1.png. It doesn't shows image and get error like this  """Gatsby.js development 404 page
There's not a page yet at /static/images/favicon.png

Preview custom 404 page

Create a React.js component in your site directory at src/pages/static/images/favicon.png.js and this page will automatically refresh to show the new page component you created.

If you were trying to reach another page, perhaps you can find it below."""

Comment: This is another issue related to the manifest plugin (I guess). Provide a favicon.png and place it to `/static/images` but this doesn't have anything to do with my provided solution.

Comment: Updated answer. Use the `__dirname` value to create a valid path or move your image to the static folder.